# Status is RUNNING all the time for loading CSV file from Storage to BiGQuery using C#

Tags: c#, csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I've created the TableReference by providing project_id, dataset_id and the name of the table.

BigQueryClient cltBigQueryByDP = BigQueryClient.Create(_strProjectId, _gCredentials);

Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.Data.TableReference reference = cltBigQueryByDP.GetTableReference("project_id", "dataset_id", "table_name");

Then, I created Schema.

TableSchema schema = new TableSchema() using TableFieldSchema.

```
   BigQueryJob job = cltBigQueryByDP.CreateLoadJob("gs://bucket_name/File_name.txt", reference, schema, new CreateLoadJobOptions()
        {
            SourceFormat = FileFormat.Csv,
            FieldDelimiter = "|",
            CreateDisposition = CreateDisposition.CreateIfNeeded,
            SkipLeadingRows = 0
        });
```

There is no error generated so far however it shows job.Status.State = RUNNING all the time.

I've been struggling for few hours but no clue to find root cause.

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the projectid and jobid so we can help debug it? It's possible the data you are loading is very large and the load job just takes a long time.

Comment: Thank you Victor for your help.
projectid = hcpinsightsanalytics
Job Id : job_a4659041_9bc1_494a_ade9_8912259a5c9a

Comment: It looks like this job failed with error "CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.". Are you providing a schema with the load job (what is it)? Could you provide an example row of the data?

Comment: Hi Victor,

I was able to solve all my issues by downloading "Google Cloud SDK Shell". It shows me the latest status about the job. When the job Shows "Done", I see errors if there are any. I solved all errors one by one and now I see my data on BQ.

The command prompt console helped me lot to see error description.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's great to hear!